# How to get simple c# classes from simple XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I am chasing my tail with xsd.exe csxsd.exe and svcutil. I must be missing something basic. I just want basic objects with basic properties and Lists or []. What am I missing?

The xsd I get is overly complex, and the objects don't include Lists or arrays.

Thanks,

Comment: So you're starting with an XML file? And I take it you're generating an XSD based on its content, then using xsd.exe to generate C# classes? If so could you take the time to mark up an XSD the way you want? With multiple levels of code generation its not much surprise you're getting...interesting...results.

Comment: so... I have used xsd.exe to generate an xsd, but the next step generating classes results in somthing far from a simple c# class with properties and properties representing collections of child objects, as in the xml

Answer (score 2):

You will need a .xsd(schema file) to use with `xsd.exe /classes` . If you don't have the .xsd file, you can generate one using a tool [like this](http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx). Most tools assume string for datatype and you may tweak the generated schema if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Why build a class that matches the XML you have to deal with and mark it up with XML serialization attributes to controls it serialization. It [can be] as easy as:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace AnXmlSample
{

  class Program
  {
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      string xml = @"<document id='3'>
                       <name>
                         document name
                       </name>
                       <foo widget-id='12' >
                         The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
                       </foo>
                     </document>" ;
      StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml) ;
      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDataFromXml)) ;
      MyDataFromXml instance = (MyDataFromXml) serializer.Deserialize( sr ) ;

      return ;
    }
  }

  [XmlRoot("document")]
  public class MyDataFromXml
  {
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get ; set ; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get ; set ; }

    [XmlElement("foo")]
    public Widget Foo { get ; set ; }

  }

  public class Widget
  {
    [XmlAttribute("widget-id")]
    public int id { get ; set ; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Content { get ; set ; }
  }

}
```

Comment: My experience is that when I look at the code generated by `xsd.exe`, "simple" is not an adjective that generally comes to mind.